# Jersey Jaxb Issues

Tags: rest, generics, jaxb, jersey

We are having a problem with generic Payload while using Jersey.  Here is our Domain object.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Event<T> {
   private T eventPayload;
   private String eventType; 
}
```

Here we have top level domain object defined. But the internal domain object is generic.

Now on the resource endpoint we have something like this as we know that the sub-domain object we were expecting is.

```
@POST
   @Path("log")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public Response writeLog(Event<LogPayload> event)
```

But this doesn’t work.
The event instance is created but the subdomain is not populated correctly.
It just tries to populate the sub-domain object with any random domain object which has the same root element as in the XML (there may be more than one).

Our Solution: 
This is our solution, but I am sure this is not  the best.

We have to modify our parent domain object have a String variable which stores XML-representation of the generic payload in a String format. For this we have had to write our own Jaxb marshaller. 
Modifications to the Event

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Event<T> {
   @XmlTransient
   private T eventPayload;
   private String eventType;
   private String payLoadXML;

// Changes to the constructor:
public Event(T eventPayload ……) {
          super();
          this.eventPayload = eventPayload;
          payLoadXML = JAXBUtils.marshall(eventPayload,false); }}
```

On the resource side once we get the parent Event object, we have to again use our own jaxb marshaller to get the required domain object from the payloadXML as follows.

```
@POST
   @Path("log")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public Response writeLog(Event<LogPayload> event)
          LogPayload log1 = (LogPayload) JAXBUtils.unMarshall(
                                     event.getPayLoadXML(),LogPayload.class);
```

So ineffect we are using our jaxbmarshaller to marshall and unmarshall the generic subdomain object before and after making the rest call….

Please lets us know if there is a better way to do this  ?

Thanks,
ND

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same question before and I don't think this will work as you originally planned. Web services (json/xml, rest/soap) usually create a service description (like wsdl) and a generic type technically cannot be part of this description. What you could do is to publish multiple services where Event is not generic anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well. I dont think that is an option. The payload could be absoulte any object. And we may add new domain objects later. We cant possible have multiple services so that Event is no longer be generic. Well the solution we have will work because we are sending the subobejct as String-XMLabd using JAXB to unmarshall it back to the required object. Only problem is that it looks hacky and may be resource intensive.

Comment: You could also use a super class (e.g. Payload) which has a map for its properties and that can serialized. You can wrap every payload with this map. Of course there are some limitations with this approach and it is not really an OOP way, but it should work. I'll set up a test project later, because I want to find a decent solution too :)

Comment: Hmm.. that may work .. but as you said not too object oriented. Again has the same pros and cons of the our approach. I am looking for a cleaner solution as well. Will be happy to know if you find one. :)